# CSS Not Loading in Python

Tags: python, html, css

I'm creating a simple page using python 3.4 and generating HTML. However the stylesheets don't load. Here is my code:

```
`#!/Python34/python
content ="""<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Spain National Team</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
</head>
<body>
<!---Body Stuff--->
</body>
</html>"""
print(content)`
```

Checking the source of the webpage,it's a well formed HTML document, but the styles don't load. My python script and css are in the same directory:
 `xampp/cgi-bin/sports/index.py`
and 
`xampp/cgi-bin/sports/styles.css`

Comment: add type attribute to the link tag type="text/css"... hope it helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open it on your *default* browser,

```
import webbrowser
content ='<html>\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>Spain National Team</title>\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>\n</head>\n<body>\n<button></button>\n</body>\n</html>'

html_file = open('sample.html', 'w')
html_file.write(content)
flnme="sample.html"
webbrowser.open_new_tab(flnme)
```